# how to group objects in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, grouping

I have an array of objects and I want to group its objects on the basis of two keys

```
var arr = [ 
  {"name": "apple", "id": "apple_0","c":'20'}, 
  {"name": "dog",   "id": "dog_1","c":'10'}, 
  {"name": "apple", "id": "apple_0","c":'30'},
  {"name": "dog",   "id": "dog_1","c":'10'},
];
```

and I am expecting result as

```
var final = [ 
  {"name": "apple", "id": "apple_0","c":'50'}, 
  {"name": "dog",   "id": "dog_1","c":'20'}
];
```

The scenario is this - I want to group object on the basis of `name` and `id`. If `name` and `id` is found in final array then make sum of its `c`.

I tried this:

```
var final = [];
for(var i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
    var obj = {};
    obj = arr[i];
    for(var j = 0; j<final.length; j++){
        if((obj[name] !== final[j].name) && (obj[id] !== final[j].id)){
          final.push(obj)
        }else{
            //addition of key `c` in existing object in `final` array 
        }
    }
}
```

but inner for loop is not working and its hanging my system due to continuous loop execution.

Please let me know how to fix it or any other logic to get the final result.

Comment: ohh... thanks @Teemu

Comment: If the `final` array starts out empty, how is `for(var j = 0; j < final.length; j++)` going to work?

Comment: so, what to do in this case? @nondestructive

Comment: should I do `if(final.length === 0){final.push(obj)}` before `for(var j = 0; j < final.length; j++)` ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution using  a `hash table` and `#reduce()` function - see demo below:

```js
var arr = [{"name": "apple", "id": "apple_0","c":'20'},{"name": "dog",   "id": "dog_1","c":'10'}, {"name": "apple", "id": "apple_0","c":'30'},{"name": "dog",   "id": "dog_1","c":'10'}];

var result = arr.reduce(function(hash){
  return function(p,c){
    if(hash[c.id])
      hash[c.id].c = +hash[c.id].c + +c.c
    else {
      hash[c.id] = hash[c.id] || c;
      p.push(hash[c.id]);
    }
    return p;
  }
}(Object.create(null)), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important;}
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
var arr = [ 
  {"name": "apple", "id": "apple_0","c":'20'}, 
  {"name": "dog",   "id": "dog_1","c":'10'}, 
  {"name": "apple", "id": "apple_0","c":'30'},
  {"name": "dog",   "id": "dog_1","c":'10'},
];


var final = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  var doPush = true;
  acc.map(v => {
    if (v.name === cur.name) {
      v.c = +v.c + +cur.c
      doPush = false;
    }
  });
  if (doPush) {
    acc.push(cur)
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log (final)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can actually use `forEach` and add the elements to an object before creating a new array

```js
var arr = [{
    "name": "apple",
    "id": "apple_0",
    "c": '20'
  },
  {
    "name": "dog",
    "id": "dog_1",
    "c": '10'
  },
  {
    "name": "apple",
    "id": "apple_0",
    "c": '30'
  },
  {
    "name": "dog",
    "id": "dog_1",
    "c": '10'
  },
];
// a new array which be created with updated value
var grouped = [];
arr.forEach(function(a) {
  // check if the element is present
  // if not then add the element
  if (!this[a.id]) {
    this[a.id] = {
      name: a.name,
      id: a.id,
      c: a.c
    };
    grouped.push(this[a.id]);
  } else {
    // if present then add the value of
    this[a.id].c += +a.c;
    
  }
}, Object.create(null));
console.log(grouped)
```

Note

Answer (score 1):

You can build a map by the id, and accumulate all the `c`'s with `reduce`.
Something like that:

```js
var arr = [{
    "name": "apple",
    "id": "apple_0",
    "c": '20'
  },
  {
    "name": "dog",
    "id": "dog_1",
    "c": '10'
  },
  {
    "name": "apple",
    "id": "apple_0",
    "c": '30'
  },
  {
    "name": "dog",
    "id": "dog_1",
    "c": '10'
  },
];

var mapResult = arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
  item = {...item}; //clone the item
  item.c = parseInt(item.c, 10);

  if (acc[item.id]) {
    acc[item.id].c += item.c
  } else {
    acc[item.id] = item;
  }

  return acc;
}, {});

const result = Object.keys(mapResult).map((key) => mapResult[key]);

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

With `Array.prototype.reduce()` and `Object.keys()` functions:

```js
var arr = [ 
  {"name": "apple", "id": "apple_0","c":'20'}, 
  {"name": "dog",   "id": "dog_1","c":'10'}, 
  {"name": "apple", "id": "apple_0","c":'30'},
  {"name": "dog",   "id": "dog_1","c":'10'},
],
    groups = arr.reduce(function(r, o){
        var k = o.name +'|'+ o.id;
        (r[k])? r[k] += +o.c : r[k] = +o.c;
        return r;
    }, {}),
    result = Object.keys(groups).map(function(k){ 
        var keys = k.split('|'); 
        return {name: keys[0], id: keys[1], c: groups[k]}; 
     });
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. obj[attribuate] eq `undifined`

   ```
   var obj = {name:'John'};
   console.log(obj[name]);
   ```
2. ```
   if((obj.name !== final[j].name) || (obj[id] !== final[j].id)){
       // push
   }else{
       // code
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [ 
  {"name": "apple", "id": "apple_0","c":'20'}, 
  {"name": "dog",   "id": "dog_1","c":'10'}, 
  {"name": "apple", "id": "apple_0","c":'30'},
  {"name": "dog",   "id": "dog_1","c":'10'},
];


  arr.reduce(function(cumm, current) {
     var indexNum = cumm.findIndex(x =>{
          return x.name == current.name;
     });      
  if(indexNum > -1) {
    cumm[indexNum].c =  Number(cumm[indexNum].c) + Number(current.c);
  } else {
    cumm.push(current);
  }
   return cumm;
 }, []);
```